# Drawing arrow with text using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made some matrices with TikZ, but I also would like to show that the second one is a focus over a sub matrix of the first one (I made an ugly example with PS here) and to add an arrow with a text above it, as the image below shows:

[image]

This is my code so far. And this is what I achieve:

[image]

I would like to know how to do the "focus" thing and how to change the "bootstrap" label size. Also, I would like to know if it possible to do this and put (a), (b) and (c) labels for each matrix and if I can change the color of the text of an specific matrix. This my first time using TikZ, so this may be a stupid question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(A) [matrix of math nodes,%
            left delimiter  = |,%
            right delimiter = |] at (0,0)
{
 a & b & c & d \\
 e & f & g & h \\ 
 i & j & l & m \\ 
 n &     o & p & q \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \fill[blue!30,opacity=.5] (A-1-1.west|-A-1-3.north) rectangle (A-3-3.south east);
\end{scope}

\matrix(B) [matrix of math nodes,%
            left delimiter  = |,%
            right delimiter = |] at (3.1cm,0)
{
 a & b & c \\
 e & f & g \\ 
 i & j & l \\ 
};

\matrix(C) [matrix of math nodes,%
            left delimiter  = |,%
            right delimiter = |] at (6cm,0cm)
{
 l & l & c \\
 f & j & i \\ 
 g & b & e \\ 
};

\matrix(D) [matrix of math nodes,%
            left delimiter  = |,%
            right delimiter = |] at (0cm,-2.5cm)
{
 l & l & c \\
 f & j & i \\ 
 g & b & e \\ 
};

\matrix(K) [matrix of math nodes] at (0cm,-2.5cm)
{
 k_{1} & k_{2} & k_{3} \\
 k_{4} & k_{5} & k_{6} \\ 
 k_{7} & k_{8} & k_{9} \\ 
};

\draw[->,thick] (B) -- (C) node [pos=0.66,above] {bootstrap};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- To change the font size of `bootstrap` you can add `font=\footnotesize` to the node options.
- You can add a node above a matrix by loading the `positioning` library and saying e.g.

  ```
  \node (a) [above=0.1cm of A] {($a$)};
  ```

  If you do the same for B and C they will be a little bit lower than the a-label, because the top of those matrices is lower. You could modify the length, but it's easier to use

  ```
  \node at (a-|B.north) {($b$)};
  ```

  which places this node at the same x-coordinate as `B.north` and the same y-coordinate as `a` (defined above).
- A brace similar to the one in your sketch can be created by adding the `decorations.pathreplacing` library, and using `decoration={brace,amplitude=8},decorate`. You can modify the amplitude. I also added an additional arrow leading to the next matrix. I don't know exactly how you wanted this though, please comment if you want any changes.
- Adding a colour name to the `matrix` options will set the colour of all the nodes in the matrix, or you could add settings for all the nodes in the `matrix` with `every node/.append style={blue}` (again, added to the `matrix` options).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace,amplitude=10}]
\matrix(A) [matrix of math nodes,%
            left delimiter  = |,%
            right delimiter = |] at (0,0)
{
 a & b & c & d \\
 e & f & g & h \\ 
 i & j & l & m \\ 
 n &     o & p & q \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \fill[blue!30,opacity=.5] (A-1-1.west|-A-1-3.north) rectangle (A-3-3.south east);
\end{scope}

\matrix(B) [matrix of math nodes,%
            left delimiter  = |,%
            right delimiter = |] at (3.1cm,0)
{
 a & b & c \\
 e & f & g \\ 
 i & j & l \\ 
};


\matrix(C) [matrix of math nodes,%
            left delimiter  = |,%
            right delimiter = |,
            every node/.append style={blue} % <-- added
            ] at (6cm,0cm)
{
 l & l & c \\
 f & j & i \\ 
 g & b & e \\ 
};

\draw [decorate,thick, red] (A-1-3.north east) -- (A-3-3.south east);
\draw [thick, red, -latex](A-2-3.east) ++(0.32cm,0) to[out=0,in=180] ([xshift=-.2cm]B.west);
\draw[->,thick] (B) -- (C) node [pos=0.66,above,font=\footnotesize] {bootstrap};

\node (a) [above=2pt of A] {($a$)};
\node at (a-|B.north) {($b$)};
\node at (a-|C.north) {($c$)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just one more question: can I change the thickness of the brace to be like the arrow that has the label "bootstrap", i.e., much more thin? Thank you.

Comment: @pceccon Of course. You'll notice that I added `ultra thick` as an option to the brace, and `very thick` to the arrow pointing from the brace. The `bootstrap` arrow has just `thick`, so if you remove `ultra` and `very` all those three should have the same thickness.