# Draw arrow in picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, pst-node

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, textwidth = 16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{pstricks}%%, pdf
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}


\psset{nodesep=2pt}
\newpsstyle{DblDash}{linestyle=dashed, dash=1pt 1.5pt, doubleline}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode=r,colsep=0.6,rowsep=0.5]

& &[name=1] $D_5$ \\
 && [name=2] $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$ &\\
[name=3] $\{e,ab\}$ &  [name=4] $\{e,a^2b\}$  &  && [name=5] $\{e,a^3b\}$ & [name=6]$\{e,a^4b\}$\\

& & [name=7] $\{e\}$
\ncline{11}{21}\ncline{12}{22}
\ncline{21}{32}\ncline{22}{32}

\ncline{1}{2}
\ncline{2}{3}\ncline{2}{4}\ncline{2}{5}\ncline{2}{6}
\ncline{3}{7}\ncline{4}{7}\ncline{5}{7}\ncline{6}{7}



\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I drew the arrows with microsoft paint but i want to draw them with latex. I look up online, and got this

`\todo[inline, color=green!40]{This is an inline comment.}`

but it tampers with the picture :'(. Any suggestions?`

How can I add coordinates so that I can make the arrow point where I want to, sort of like the answer to this [Drawing arrow with text using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170819/drawing-arrow-with-text-using-tikz)

Comment: `\ncline{11}{21}\ncline{12}{22}` makes no sense. There are no such nodenames. I suppose you mean `\ncline{1,1}{2,1}\ncline{1,2}{2,2}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to use alpha-numeric `name`s.

The following inserts two extra nodes at a distance of 15pt (`nodesep=15pt`) to the right of node `F` (horizontally), one on the same level as node `B` and the other at the same level as node `F` (vertically). Then, the two arrows are drawn, followed by the placement of the labels using a `[l]`eft reference point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\psset{nodesep=2pt}
\SpecialCoor
\newpsstyle{DblDash}{linestyle=dashed, dash=1pt 1.5pt, doubleline}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode=r,colsep=0.6,rowsep=0.5]
  & & [name=A] $D_5$ \\
  & & [name=B] $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$ & \\
  [name=C] $\{e,ab\}$ & [name=D] $\{e,a^2b\}$ & & & [name=E] $\{e,a^3b\}$ & [name=F]$\{e,a^4b\}$\\
  & & [name=G] $\{e\}$
  \ncline{A}{B}
  \ncline{B}{C}\ncline{B}{D}\ncline{B}{E}\ncline{B}{F}
  \ncline{C}{G}\ncline{D}{G}\ncline{E}{G}\ncline{F}{G}
  \pnode([nodesep=15pt]F|B){B-right}
  \pnode(B-right|F){F-right}
  \ncline{<-}{B}{B-right}\rput[l]([nodesep=5pt]B-right){Sylow 5-subgroup}
  \ncline{<-}{F}{F-right}\rput[l]([nodesep=5pt]F-right){Sylow 2-subgroups}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

Here's a view on the reference points (from the [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf), section **24 Placing and rotating whatever**, p 42):

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what these lines do? \pnode([nodesep=15pt]F|B){B-right}
  \pnode(B-right|F){F-right}
  \ncline{<-}{B}{B-right}\rput[l]([nodesep=5pt]B-right){Sylow 5-subgroup}
  \ncline{<-}{F}{F-right}\rput[l]([nodesep=5pt]F-right){Sylow 2-subgroups}

Comment: @abe15: This uses notation as defined by `\SpecialCoor` (section **54 Special coordinates**, p 145 of the [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf)): `\pnode(<coor>){<node>}` places a node `<node>` at location `<coor>`. `<coor>`, specified as `[nodesep=15pt]F|B`, takes the x-coordinate of the `X` and the y-coordinate of `Y` [in the format `X|Y`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rdaD0.png). [`[nodesep=15pt]F`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vN00c.png) is situated `15pt` to the right of `F`.

Comment: using `\rput` with `\ncline` is awkward. `\ncline{->}{B-right}{B}>{Sylow 5-subgroup}` does the same more elegant.

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks; didn't know about that notation. Any documentation on that?

Comment: sure, see `texdoc pst-node` pp 19--21

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, textwidth = 16cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{pstricks}%%, pdf
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{nodesep=2pt}
\newpsstyle{DblDash}{linestyle=dashed, dash=1pt 1.5pt, doubleline}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode=r,colsep=0.6,rowsep=0.5]
& &[name=1] $D_5$ \\
 && [name=2] $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$ &\\
[name=3] $\{e,ab\}$ &  [name=4] $\{e,a^2b\}$  &  && [name=5] $\{e,a^3b\}$ & [name=6]$\{e,a^4b\}$\\

& & [name=7] $\{e\}$
\ncline{11}{21}\ncline{12}{22}
\ncline{21}{32}\ncline{22}{32}

\ncline{1}{2}
\ncline{2}{3}\ncline{2}{4}\ncline{2}{5}\ncline{2}{6}
\ncline{3}{7}\ncline{4}{7}\ncline{5}{7}\ncline{6}{7}

\psline[linewidth=1pt]{<-}(1,2)(4,2)
\rput[l](4.2,2){Sylow 5-subgroup}
\psline[linewidth=1pt]{<-}(5.2,1)(6,1)
\rput[l](6.2,1){Sylow 2-subgroups}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use *always* relative coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\psset{nodesep=2pt}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode=r,colsep=0.6,rowsep=0.75]
                    &                      &[name=1] $D_5$                 & \\
                    &                      &[name=2] $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$ &[name=A]\\
[name=3] $\{e,ab\}$ &[name=4] $\{e,a^2b\}$ & & & [name=5] $\{e,a^3b\}$ &    
        [name=6]$\{e,a^4b\}$  & [name=B]                                            \\
                    &                      &[name=7] $\{e\}$
\ncline{1}{2}
\ncline{2}{3}\ncline{2}{4}\ncline{2}{5}\ncline{2}{6}
\ncline{3}{7}\ncline{4}{7}\ncline{5}{7}\ncline{6}{7}
\ncline[linewidth=1pt,arrows=->,nodesepA=2cm]{A}{A}>{Sylow 5-subgroup}
\ncline[linewidth=1pt,arrows=->,nodesepA=1cm]{B}{B}>{Sylow 2-subgroups}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or without using `nodesep` and a simple connection:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\psset{nodesep=2pt}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode=r,colsep=0.6,rowsep=0.75]
                    &                      &[name=1] $D_5$                 & \\
                    &                      &[name=2] $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,a^4\}$ 
      & & & & & [name=A] Sylow 5-subgroup\\
[name=3] $\{e,ab\}$ &[name=4] $\{e,a^2b\}$ &                               & 
      &[name=5] $\{e,a^3b\}$ &[name=6]$\{e,a^4b\}$  & &[name=B]Sylow 2-subgroups \\
                    &                      &[name=7] $\{e\}$
\ncline{1}{2}
\ncline{2}{3}\ncline{2}{4}\ncline{2}{5}\ncline{2}{6}
\ncline{3}{7}\ncline{4}{7}\ncline{5}{7}\ncline{6}{7}
\ncline[linewidth=1pt,arrows=->]{A}{2}
\ncline[linewidth=1pt,arrows=->]{B}{6}
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]